# Taking Count using inline query statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get a count of columns from 2 tables. I have written a SQL statement like this :

`SELECT COUNT (assetnum) asset,
    COUNT (description) description,
    COUNT (
    CASE
        WHEN totdowntime > 0
        THEN assetnum
    END) totdowntime,
    (SELECT COUNT (wonum)
    FROM workorder
    WHERE assetnum IN
        (SELECT assetnum FROM asset WHERE TO_CHAR (installdate,'YYYY') ='2011'
        )
    ) AS wo_count
FROM asset
WHERE TO_CHAR (installdate, 'YYYY') = '2011`

I am not getting it why  the above code is not working even the inline statement is returning single value ?

The data is like this:

asset table :

```
assetnum   description  totdowntime  insatlldate   siteid
1000        ABC         1            01-01-2011    AGN
1001        DEF         1.5          02-01-2011    AGN
1002        AKK         5            03-01-2011    AGN
1003        LSDL        3            04-01-2011    AGN
1004        JKDF        3.3          01-02-2012    AGN
1005        DFJK        4.5          01-02-2012    AGN
```

Workorder table :

```
wonum   siteid  assetnum
  1      AGN    1000
  2      AGN    1001
  3      AGN    1002
  4      DVN    1000
  5      DVN    1001
  6      AGN    1004
```

Desired Output :

```
asset_cnt   descrpition_cnt totdowntime_cnt wonum_cnt
    6          6             6                4
```

The Output I get :

`Error:ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

Comment: Can you post some sample data.

Comment: You need to create some sample / test data to demonstrate (to us, and yourself) the behaviour that you want.  Then show us three things; the test data, the results that you want, the results you actually get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query,

```
SELECT COUNT (A.assetnum) AS asset, COUNT (A.description) AS description,
COUNT ( A.totdowntime) AS totdowntime,
COUNT (AN.wonum)
FROM asset A
INNER JOIN workorder AN
ON (A.assetnum  = AN.assetnum )
```

WHERE TO_CHAR (A.installdate, 'YYYY') = '2011';

Use alias for installdate as per the table A or AN
You can use case where it is required

```
COUNT (CASE WHEN A.totdowntime > 0 THEN A.assetnum END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.assetnum) as asset,
       COUNT(a.description) as description,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.totdowntime > 0 AND a.assetnum IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) as totdowntime,
       (SELECT COUNT(wo.wonum)
        FROM workorder wo
        WHERE wo.assetnum = a.assetnum
       ) as wo_count
FROM asset a
WHERE installdate >= DATE '2011-01-01' AND
      installdate < DATE '2012-01-01';
```

Notes:

- The first two `COUNT()` are probably going to return the same value.  Remember that `COUNT()` counts the number of non-NULL values.
- I prefer `SUM()` rather than `COUNT()` for counting values from expressions.  But `COUNT()` is also fine.
- I think you want a correlated subquery for counting from `workorder`.
- Table aliases and qualified column names are a good idea in any query.